# Updating modules creates An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally error

Tags: 7, ajax, updating

Drupal 7.77. I have three modules that need to be updated. Trying to update any one of them results in this error:

> An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally. Debugging information follows. Path: http://www.mywebsite.com/authorize.php?batch=1&id=1069&op=do StatusText: ResponseText: ReadyState: 4.

Update Manager shows:

> Notice: Undefined index: log in update_authorize_update_batch_finished() (line 187 of /home/mywebsite.com/modules/update/update.authorize.inc).
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in update_authorize_update_batch_finished() (line 187 of /home/mywebsite.com/modules/update/update.authorize.inc).
> Notice: Undefined index: log in update_authorize_update_batch_finished() (line 236 of /home/mywebsite.com/modules/update/update.authorize.inc).
> Update failed!

I am not a coder and have no idea where to start.

Comment: What modules, from what versions and how exactly did you update? Like what commands in what environment? Did you flush cache? Do you have command line access? Please update your question and add more details. Many thanks 

Comment: Thanks leymannx for the reply. I don't think the issue is related to a specific module because I tried updating all of them together and one at a time, but the modules are Features 7x-2.12, Field Collection 7x-1.1, Meda Youtube 7x-3.9.The procedure I used was modules/update from the admin menu. Yes, the cache was flushed. To maintain the website, I use a dummy domain in a hosted environment. No, I don't have command-line access. I probably could enable access, but I have no knowledge of commands.

Comment: Should I close this thread as no one seem interested?

Comment: No, leave it open. Maybe reach out to https://drupal.slack.com/ to find others that might discuss your issue more widely.